# Autowiring a service into a validator

Tags: spring, validation, hibernate-validator, autowired, spring-3

This example is a bit contrived; I've simplified it to remove extraneous details and to focus on the problem I am having. I have a validator that looks like this:

```
@Component
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

    @Autowired
    UsernameService usernameService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername uniqueUsername) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return !usernameService.exists(s);
    }   
}
```

I call the validator from my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping
public void checkUsername(Model model, User user) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validateProperty(user, "username");
    model.addAttribute("error", constraintViolations.size() > 0);
}
```

However, I keep getting an `NullPointerException` exception. I added a breakpoint in my validator and saw that `usernameService` was `null`. Why isn't it getting autowired? Initially I thought it was because I hadn't annotated the validator with `@Component`, but I still have the same problem even after annotating it. The `UsernameService` class has already been annotated with `@Service` and I can verify that its constructor is getting called.

I am new to Spring, so I'm not even sure if it is alright to wire a service into a validator. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Spring, you need to obtain `ValidatorFactory` (or `Validator` itself) via `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` instead of `Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()`, as described [in the reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring).

```
@Autowired
Validator validator;

@RequestMapping 
public void checkUsername(Model model, User user) { 
    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validateProperty(user, "username"); 
    model.addAttribute("error", constraintViolations.size() > 0); 
}
```

-

```
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

**EDIT:** But perhaps the better way to do it is to use Spring MVC's automatic validation with `@Valid` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping  
public void checkUsername(Model model, @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {  
    if (result.hasErrors()) {   
        ...
    }
}
```

This also requires `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in the config.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's exactly what I was looking for. I was going through the reference documentation but I was searching for things like "autowiring services into constraints". Thanks again!

Comment: I like the edit with the @Valid. Wish I could upvote more than once :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new validator, you have to autowire or inject it to controller. The `NPE` from the service not being injected as your validator is not being created/managed by spring.

Comment: If I autowire the validator directly, I need the `ConstraintValidatorContext` to call `isValid`. How do I get that? It also seems a little kludgey to me. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?