# Can I Autowired one Repository inside Spring boot custom validator

Tags: java, spring-boot

I Create one Custom Validator with Spring Boot:

```
public class AberturaMatriculaValidator implements Validator {
    @Autowired
    IQualificacao iQualificacao;
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return AberturaMatricula.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {//TODO Necessita Validações mais complexas, como verificar se o valor existe em uma determinada lista e tal.
        AberturaMatricula obj = (AberturaMatricula) target;
        List<TbQualificacao> qualificacaoList = iQualificacao.findByNatureza("IMOVEIS");
        System.out.println(qualificacaoList.size());
    }
}
```

and add he in my Controller:

```
@RestController
            @RequestMapping("/ri")
            public class RIController {
            @InitBinder("aberturaMatricula")
                protected void initAberturaMatriculaBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
                    binder.addValidators(new AberturaMatriculaValidator());
                }

            @RequestMapping(value =  "/selo/abertura/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
                public AberturaMatricula selarAbertura(@RequestBody @Valid AberturaMatricula aberturaMatricula){
            ...
             }
            }
```

So inside my validator the

```
@Autowired
IQualificacao iQualificacao;
```

don`t work, if I put this repository in my controller, works fine

---------------------SOLUTION (tks for @sanluck)----------

My validator:

```
public class AberturaMatriculaValidator implements Validator {

    private IQualificacao iQualificacao;

    public AberturaMatriculaValidator(IQualificacao iQualificacao) {
        this.iQualificacao = iQualificacao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return AberturaMatricula.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {//TODO Necessita Validações mais complexas, como verificar se o valor existe em uma determinada lista e tal.
        AberturaMatricula obj = (AberturaMatricula) target;

    }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ri")
public class RIController {

    @Autowired
    IQualificacao iQualificacao;

    @InitBinder("aberturaMatricula")
    protected void initAberturaMatriculaBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new AberturaMatriculaValidator(iQualificacao));
    }
...
}
```

Comment: IoC only works on beans managed by Spring. Your custom validator isn't one.

Comment: So, how can I validate some value when I need to get in DB? I trying to autowire the Validator in my Controller, but with no success

Comment: You need to register the validator in Spring. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587317/autowiring-a-service-into-a-validator). After this, you should be able to autowire things inside the validator.

Comment: @damobros Yes, but I need to know where this come. for example my base class, if the field is in object inside objet, I need to know the Base class, how can I does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Configuration` to your application for registering your `AberturaMatriculaValidator`:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {

@Autowired
IQualificacao iQualificacao;

@Bean
public AberturaMatriculaValidator aberturaMatriculaValidator() {
    return new AberturaMatriculaValidator(iQualificacao);
}
}
```

Also you must create constructor `AberturaMatriculaValidator(IQualificacao iqualificao)`.

Comment: But and here?    @InitBinder("aberturaMatricula")
                protected void initAberturaMatriculaBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
                    binder.addValidators(new AberturaMatriculaValidator());
                }