# Spring Boot with Validation - Inject repository inside custom validator gives Null

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-data

Although I found some similar problems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47245122/spring-hibernate-autowired-is-null-in-constraintvalidator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368190/can-i-autowired-one-repository-inside-spring-boot-custom-validator) for example) it did not completely answer my problem, as I used spring Boot 2.4.4, or simply don't work. My problem is that repository becomes `null` during second (JPA) validation. Here is the detail :

I use Spring Boot, and Bean Validation, via the `spring-boot-starter-validation dependency`.
I have  a custom validator to check if an email exists in database. First I declare the `@EmailExisting` annotation :

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EmailExisting {
    String message() default "Email already exists";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then the custom validator, with the repository injected to check Database :

```java
public class EmailValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<EmailExisting, String> {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (!users.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally the SPRING MVC part, with the `@Valid` annotation to trigger validation :

```java
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/users")
    public ResponseEntity addUSer(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {

        user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        user.setLastName(StringUtils.capitalize(user.getLastName()));
        user.setFirstName(StringUtils.capitalize(user.getFirstName()));
        userRepository.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Problem:
When I test the endpoint, I have a `NullPointerException`.
At first, during MVC validation the repository is correctly injected. But after, when we call `save()` method to save the entity in the controller, the control triggers again, and the repository becomes `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

I found a workaround, to deactivate control on JPA side, with the following configuration :
`spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`

It works well, but I think it should be possible to have the repository injected in the 2 cases?

All code is in [my repository](https://github.com/smaestri/poc-spring-validation)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try constructor di?

Comment: I tried to add in `EmailValidator` to add contructor : `public EmailValidator(UserRepository userRepository) {this.userRepository = userRepository;}` but now when calling `save()` I have `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.demo.EmailValidator.<init>()`